# How to include CSS into a IntraWeb Project?

Tags: html, css, delphi, delphi-xe6, intraweb

## Explanation:

I created a new Standalone IntraWeb application via the "IntraWeb Application Wizard", and i put some buttons and edits with events inside, all the things worked fine, but the buttons and edits needs some style, because they are ugly.

## Objective:

I want to stylize them using CSS to overwrite default style and add some new styles.

## Problem:

I cannot find how to include a CSS File to my project for later using it in the **StyleSheet** property on my `TIWForm`.

## What I've Tried:

I tried to put the css file manually into the Debug folder "same folder of the .exe" and too i tried to click File -> New -> Others -> CSS Stylesheet and then pasted the css code and saved it into the Debug folder "same folder of the .exe".

I need to solve this problem, otherwise i will be unable from using IntraWeb App.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Once you've created and saved your CSS file, you simply set the `TIWForm.StyleSheet.FileName` to the name of that file.

Comment: i did try to set the FileName property of my TIWForm on the object inspector to my css filename but it do not work

Comment: Setting the filename certainly does work, as does setting the URL. You have to actually apply the styles. There's an example of using a custom .CSS in the Demos for Intraweb. I don't have IW installed for XE6, but in older versions it was in the public documents folder (Win 7 has it in `C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\5.0\Demos\Intraweb\Win32`); there's a folder named `Features`. If you open the project in that folder and poke around, you'll see it uses a custom .CSS named azweb.css for styling some things. (And saying "do not work" without any details is meaningless.)

Comment: Sorry for the "do not work" the problem that i am getting is file not found, i am using the standalone and probably the css file are not being deploy into the server, but i will try to see the samples here

Comment: Ok. Use the URL, and make it relative to your project (eg., if you're putting the CSS file on your server in the `files` folder, reference it as `./files/your.css`. If you're referencing it by filename, you can also use `.\files\your.css`.

Comment: using reference by filename `.\files\css\bee.css` i got error msg from console: `"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://127.0.0.1:55227/Files/files/css/bee.css"`

Comment: oh, now i used `..\files\css\bee.css` and i gor the path correct but still do not find the file -> `"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://127.0.0.1:55279/files/css/bee.css"`

Comment: This is a folder issue, and I can't see your directory structure from here. The folder where you're placing the file has to be available to the web server (or your app). Is there a folder at whatever your web root is + `/files/css`? I don't know what you've configured as your web root folder. This isn't an Intraweb problem now; it's a configuration issue, and I can't help with that because I can't see your configuration from here. Sorry.

Answer (score 5):

The Standalone IntraWeb application by default looks for a folder named `\wwwroot\` in the application directory. The `Stylesheet.Filename` path is relativ to this folder.

To solve your problem, just create `..\Win32\Debug\wwwroot\` and place your `bee.css` in there. Then in the object inspector change `StyleSheet.Filename` to `bee.css`.

If you prefer setting it up per code, you can do it in the `onRender` event like this:

```
procedure TIWSomeForm.IWAppFormRender(Sender: TObject); 
begin   
  Stylesheet.Filename := 'bee.css'; 
end;
```

If you want to change the content folder, you can do the following:

```
function IWServerController: TIWServerController;
begin
  Result := TIWServerController(GServerController);
  gsc.ContentPath := 'Full\Path\Here';
end;
```

Be aware that you need to do this in the constructor!

Documentation can be found here: http://docs.atozed.com/docs.dll/classes/TIWServerControllerBase.html

PS: Don't forget to apply your CSS classes in the `Css` property.

Comment: idea: instead of using "..\Win32\Debug\wwwroot\" one can improve the work flow by changing the output folder to a more convenient folder (I use the same folder as the main DRPJ folder). now you don't have to navigate all those folders to change the CSS file :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Locate your compiled (exe) file (usually located in \Win32\Debug).
2. Create a folder named 'wwwroot' there and put your CSS file in that folder. (The folder MUST have this exact name. Any other name will not work!)
3. Click your form and edit the StyleSheet property:

[image]

### Hint: The background image can be edited the same way.

Note that you might prefer to use

but Intraweb is using .